# How to inject `time` attribute based on certain json key value?

Tags: fluentd

I am still new on fluentd, I've tried various configuration, but I am stuck.

Suppose I have this record pushed to fluend that has _epoch to tell the epoch time the record is created.

```
{"data":"dummy", "_epoch": <epochtime_in_second>}
```

Instead of using `time` attribute being processed by fluentd, I want to override the time with this `_epoch` field. How to produce fluentd output with `time` overriden?

I've tried this

```
# TCP input to receive logs from the forwarders
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

# HTTP input for the liveness and readiness probes
<source>
  @type http
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 9880
</source>

# rds2fluentd_test
<filter rds2fluentd_test.*>
  @type parser
  key_name _epoch
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<time>.*)$/
    time_type unixtime
    utc true
  </parse>
</filter>


<filter rds2fluentd_test.*>
  @type stdout
</filter>

<match rds2fluentd_test.*>
  @type s3
  @log_level debug
  aws_key_id "#{ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']}"
  aws_sec_key "#{ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']}"
  s3_bucket foo-bucket
  s3_region ap-southeast-1
  path ingestion-test-01/${_db}/${_table}/%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M/

  #s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}
  # if you want to use ${tag} or %Y/%m/%d/ like syntax in path / s3_object_key_format,
  # need to specify tag for ${tag} and time for %Y/%m/%d in <buffer> argument.
  <buffer time,_db,_table>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluent/s3
    timekey 1m # 5 minutes partition
    timekey_wait 10s
    timekey_use_utc true # use utc
    chunk_limit_size 256m
  </buffer>

  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
  store_as json
</match>
```

But upon receiving data like above, it shows warning error like this:

```
#0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="parse failed no implicit conversion of Integer into Hash" location="/usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.10.4/lib/fluent/plugin/filter_parser.rb:110:in `rescue in filter_with_time'" tag="rds2fluentd_test." time=1590578507 record={....
```

Comment: even i am facing the same error, could you find a fix??

Answer (score 0):

was getting the same warning message, setting `hash_value_field parsed` under filter section solved the issue.